# MySQL procedure to add a nullified row with the current date

Tags: mysql, procedure

Within a procedure, I am trying to add a row with the current date -- for when an entry has not been made on a particular day. Why is this not working?

The last row of time_data:

```
| id |  the_date  | time_in | time_out | duration
| -- | -----------|---------|----------|----------
| 39 | 2023-08-18 | 10:50:30 | 14:19:18 | 03:28:47
```

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE missedDayProcedure()
    BEGIN
      DECLARE ID INT;
      DECLARE the_date DATE;
  
      SELECT MAX(ID) INTO ID FROM time_data;
      SELECT the_date INTO the_date FROM time_data WHERE ID = ID;
  
      IF CURDATE() >= DATE_ADD(the_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN
          INSERT INTO time_data VALUES (ID + 1, CURDATE(), NULL, NULL, NULL);
      END IF;
   END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `WHERE ID = ID` is true for every row. Don't use a variable with the same name as a column.

Comment: If you want the last date, use `SELECT the_date INTO last_date FROM time_data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`